# Linking yaml-cpp with conan

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, yaml-cpp

I'm using `yaml-cpp` from [conan center](https://conan.io/center/yaml-cpp), in my conan file, `yaml-cpp/0.6.3`, along with other dependencies.

The rest of the libraries link properly, so there must be something missing in my `CMakeLists.txt` file. (Maybe some extra definition...?)

Until now, with those lines:

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

It worked fine (For other libraries, like bullet, glm...)

At link time, problems with missing implementation arise:

```
cmake --build build --config Debug --target all -- -j 10
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/my-project.dir/src/MySourceFile.cpp.o: in function `YAML::Node::Scalar[abi:cxx11]() const':
/home/my-user/.conan/data/yaml-cpp/0.6.3/_/_/package/82ef5eac51c38971dea2fd342dd55ddf2ddfbbc3/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:169: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::node_data::empty_scalar[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/my-project.dir/src/MySource.cpp.o: in function `tojson::loadyaml(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/my-user/my-project/lib/nlohmann/tojson.hpp:162: undefined reference to `YAML::LoadFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Seems that the problem is that `YAML::LoadFile` appears to be undefined.

(I've tried using it without `tojson` also)

```cpp
YAML::Node test = YAML::LoadFile("test.yaml");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is okay, but your profile is misconfigured.

> undefined reference to `YAML::LoadFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

You have to update your libcxx setting:

```
conan profile update settings.compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 default
```

More info about: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_gcc_abi.html

Comment: I've been searching for a solution for hours, and this one fixes it! Thanks!!